# Como encontrar um elemento numa lista sem usar a biblioteca List?

Tags: f#

Vamos dizer que eu tenho uma lista como essa:

```
let A = ["Alunos", ["João", "Maria", "Paulo"], "Professores", ["Amélia", "Betina", "Carolina"]
```

Como eu consigo fazer uma função que consiga encontrar a palavra Alunos e retornar a lista seguinte (nesse caso, ["João", "Maria", "Paulo"])? Importante! Sem usar a biblioteca List

Comment: use um [`for´](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/loops-for-in-expression) pra percorrer todos os elementos, compare o _pesquisado_ com cada um dos elementos; se for igual, você encontrou. (tente!! caso tenha dúvidas no código você posta a pergunta ;])

Comment: mas f# suporta loops? eu não sabia disso :(